# Kaprekar Number

Tags: number-theory

can somebody please explain why 4879 isn't a Kaprekar number? It's square is 23804641, which can be divided into 238 and 04641. When we add these two, the sum is 4879.
Thanks.

Comment: [It is](https://oeis.org/A006886). Apparently, there is a mistake on Wikipedia article.

Comment: I thought 6174 is a Kaprekar number. It is one where the process of ordering digits in ascending and subtracting from number obtained by ordering digits in descending and repeating the process for any (not all digits same) for digit number leads to it.

Comment: The English Wikipedia page doesn't list $4879$, but the German, French, Italian and Japanese pages do. It is also listed in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A006886

Comment: Maybe the solution was omitted because $04641$ starts with a leading zero.

Comment: I fixed the english Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

the digits must be grouped from left to right according to the number of digits the number has. Here:

thhe given no.is 4879.
therefore the sum has to be taken like:

```
          2380+4641
```

which is not equal to 4879.

Comment: No, the digits do not have to be divided evenly and in some cases you can't divide them evenly at all b/c there are an odd number.  Example $297^2=88209$ where you have five digits, you set off the first two from the last three.  For $4879^2$ you set off the first three digits from the last five, not four and four.